# Help understanding Picard Group

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals, exact-sequence

I have a long definition for Picard groups, but it is too abstract for me to really understand and apply.

[image: definition]

Could someone give an example or two on how to calculate the Picard group for a quadratic integer ring?

Also the relevance of the exact sequence?

Comment: In the language of algebraic number theory this is also called the class group, right ?

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathcal{O}_K$ is the ring of integers of a number field $K$ then ${\rm Pic}(\mathcal{O}_K)$ is just the ideal class group of $\mathcal{O}_K$. For quadratic number fields we have many examples, say, where this group is trivial. In the imaginary quadratic case $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$, $d$ squarefree and $d<0$ exactly for
$$
d=−1, −2, −3, −7, −11, −19, −43, −67, −163.
$$
You will find several computations on MSE of class groups for quadratic number fields. See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046496/how-to-calculate-the-ideal-class-group-of-a-quadratic-number-field), how to do it.
In fact, a Dedekind domain $A$ is a principal ideal domain if and
only if ${\rm Pic}(A)$ is trivial.