# Fact about sum of ideal classes in the ideal class group

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideal-class-group

Let $K$ be a number field with  ring of integers $\cal{O}_K$ and class group $\cal{O}_K$. Let $\mathfrak{p},\mathfrak{q}$ be two integral ideals such that $\mathfrak{p}\mathfrak{q} = (\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in \cal{O}_K$. Then, why do we have that $[\mathfrak{p}]+[\mathfrak{q}] = \bar{0}$ in $Cl(\cal{O}_K)$?

Comment: Isn't the operation in $\operatorname{Cl}(\mathcal{O}_K)$ multiplication of ideals? Why are you adding ideal classes? Do you mean $[\mathfrak{p} + \mathfrak{q}]$?

Comment: Yes, it is. Can  you check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046496/how-to-calculate-the-ideal-class-group-of-a-quadratic-number-field please?

Comment: Because $(\alpha)$ is a principal ideal, hence by definition $[(\alpha)] = \bar 0$.

Comment: I see, I presume the author of that answer has used additive notation because the class group turns out to be isomorphic to the Klein four group (which is abelian)

Comment: @Hw Chu, but we do not use additive notation ?

Comment: $[\mathfrak p] + [\mathfrak q] = [\mathfrak p \mathfrak q]$ isn't it? You used $+$ in the ideal classes simply because $Cl(\mathcal O_K)$ is abelian for all $K$.

Answer (score 1):

The author of the answer you linked in the comments refers to the ideal class of the principal ideal $\mathfrak{p}\mathfrak{q} = (\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_K$. In $\operatorname{Cl}(\mathcal{O}_K)$, this means that $[\mathfrak{p}\mathfrak{q}] = \bar{1}$, or that $[\mathfrak{p}][\mathfrak{q}] = \bar{1}$ (when we write everything multiplicatively). If we write additively (which is often done to highlight the commutativity of a group), we have $[\mathfrak{p}] + [\mathfrak{q}] = \bar{0}$. Note that in the answer you linked, the author goes on to show that the class group is isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_2$, which is an abelian group, so the additive notation highlights this.